# Two dimensional array with static and dynamic values

Tags: javascript

```
  var currntTab = dijit.byId(selcp).title;
  var urlValue = document.getElementById("restUrlValue").value;
```

- I want to form two dimensional array with above two values.
- currntTab will have constant value and urlValue differs.

The output should be something like this :

```
myarray[currntTab][0] = "home 192.168.1.8"
myarray[currntTab][1] = "home 192.168.1.22"
myarray[currntTab][2] = "home 192.168.1.7"
```

Comment: We need more info here...

Comment: You're much better using an object for this: e.g. `tabs = { one: 'home 192.168.1.8', two: 'home 192.168.1.22' }`.

Comment: Can you paste your inprogress code here..?

Comment: Is `dijit.byId(selcp).title` a number?

Comment: @Teemu : According to the question posted by OP, that will be a constant string called `home`.

Comment: @TheDarkKnight Looks like I've somehow missed that : ). Bobby: If `currentTab` is a string, it can't be used as an index. You need to use an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_object_initializers) instead of an array.

Comment: @Teemu Well, we don't need to use the currentTab as an index, rather the index will be ints only. The current tab of every first column of every row (with indices like 0,1,2, etc ) will be just constants. As you can see, in my answer below , the currentTab String object that i have is just a constant and not an index. @Vikash Pandey Your answer is also good, apart from the fact that you have made `currntTab` as an array, which is unnecessary since it's always gonna be a constant. We make arrays when we have dynamic values , but in case of constants it must be a simple variable.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do the job for you :

```
var currntTab = 'home';
var urlValue  = '192.168.1.8';

var myArray = [[currntTab,urlValue]];
console.log(myArray[0][0]+" "+myArray[0][1]);
```

See the working Fiddle here : [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BQC2N/)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this,

store all your tab value and url value in separate Arrays.

```
var myarray = {};
var currntTabArray = []; // contains all the tab value 
var urlValueArray = []; // contains all the url value

for(var i=0; i<currntTabArray.length; i++ ) {
    for(var j=0; j<urlValueArray.length; j++ ) {
       myarray[currntTabArray[i]][j]= urlValueArray[j];
    }
}
```

hope this will help you...